# parcel.js project. web components do not work on IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer, babeljs, custom-element, parceljs

Here is my project:

https://github.com/march23hare/parcel-scaffolding-web-components/tree/test-custom-elements

My goal is:

1. Using Parcel.js bundler.
2. Vanilla JS and Web Components are the major tech-stack.
3. Support IE 11.

So I make a configuration for babel, .babelrc.

And use Web Components' polyfill(https://github.com/webcomponents/custom-elements).

Then bundle it with Parcel.js.

The test component work properly on the modern browsers.

But for IE 11, it didn't.

I have no idea what is causing the problem.

Could you please help me?

Comment: Check dev-tools in IE to reveal any scripting error

Comment: To support IE11, it is usually sufficient to install babel-polyfill, and import that as the first line of your rendered application. 

import 'babel-polyfill';

Comment: I solve this problem myself. But not clear. Anyway I did remove some plugin settings from .babelrc then it was suddenly solved.

Comment: But there is another issue popped out. The CSS code written in a custom element class is not converted properly by postcss & postcss-presets-env. I decided to pause this project and to use Polymer LitElement.